# primefaces export Excel chart

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts, export

According [Primefaces DataExporter - Basic](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml), I can export excel file. But I want to exchange export in chart format. my point is instead of `target="tbl"` use `target="chart"`.How can I do it.
thank you.

Comment: The `target` parameter specifies the id of the datatable you want to export, not the export format. Details can be found in the Primefaces development guide:  https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf

Comment: thank you, but how can  I export chart in excel file.

Comment: You just can't... Exporting charts in excel is not supported

Answer (score 1):

You just can't... Exporting charts in excel is not supported. PrimeFaces 'exporting' is not a full blown reporting tool Use something like jasper-reports or similar (I have no preference, don't use one, so don't take this as an advice to use specifically jasper-reports). Use Google to find similar tools